# Resetting an Object position within Swift

Tags: ios, swift

So I am trying to reset the y location of an object "puppy" once my resetButton is tapped. Right now, when you hit the reset button the first time, nothing happens. If you hit it a second time, it goes to a weird location too high. If you keep hitting it, the object stays in that weird place. Do I have my IBAction in the wrong place maybe? And is that a bad code?

p.s. - the commented out stuff at the bottom is stuff I've tried, but hasn't worked.

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

    @IBAction func resetButton() {


    puppy.center.y = 131




    //puppy.frame = CGRectMake(puppy.frame.origin.y, 131,puppy.frame.size.width,puppy.frame.size.height)
    /*UIView.animateWithDuration(0, delay: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: {
        self.puppy.alpha = 1
        self.puppy.center.y = 131  
        }, completion: nil)*/

}

}
```

Comment: What is the original position of `puppy`?

Comment: I'm not sure how to find that. Is it (67,131)? imgur.com/2x24IUb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var location = CGPoint(x:0, y:131)
puppy.center = location
```

Try this!  Here you specify a var of type CGPoint which you can then set the center of the puppy to be at.